# Firebase Admin Storage: The caller does not have permission

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-storage

I have a project that uses the default bucket on Firebase Admin.

I have the following line:

```
const [url] = await blob.getSignedUrl({ action: 'read', expires: Date.now() + 60 * 1000, contentType: mimetype })
```

When my HTTPS callable function is called, the line above throws the error bellow:

```
Unhandled error Error: The caller does not have permission
    at Gaxios._request (/workspace/node_modules/gaxios/build/src/gaxios.js:129:23)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
    at async Compute.requestAsync (/workspace/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/oauth2client.js:368:18)
    at async GoogleAuth.signBlob (/workspace/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/googleauth.js:655:21)
    at async sign (/workspace/node_modules/@google-cloud/storage/build/src/signer.js:97:35) {
  name: 'SigningError'
}
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Please give full code of upload file also check security rules in firebase console

Comment: This is happen on firebase admin SDK, all rules are by passed by the admin. And all rules are open.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- There is already an open [GitHub issue](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/issues/782) on this. If this is
  exactly what you are looking for, you can go through the solution
  listed on GitHub issue which is :

  Go to your project's `Cloud Console > IAM & admin > IAM`, Find the `App Engine default service account` and add the `Service Account Token Creator` role to that member. This will allow your app to create signed public URLs to the images.
- If it did not work for you, try updating IAM roles. From the
  firebaseSA.json file look if the associated email has these roles:

  ```
  Firebase Admin SDK Administrator ,Service Agent, Service Account
  Token Creator ,Pub/Sub Publisher, Storage Admin
  ```
- If still it didn’t work for you, try running your application with
  another Service account that has all possible Cloud Storage
  permissions, does it work? If yes, it would mean that your current
  Service requires additional permissions to execute the function. You
  can check what permissions to give in the [Cloud Storage IAM Roles](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam-roles)